# First element is removed when pressing btn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery and bootstrap to create a kanban board.

I am adding a new column when clicking `Add News Column` I get a new row. However, when clicking `X` only the first row is deleted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // add lane
  $('#colBtn').click(function() {
    $("#laneSection").append($("#swimlane").clone());
  });

  // add row
  $('#rowBtn').click(function() {
    $("#lane").append($("#laneItem").clone());
  });
  
  $("#del").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#swimlane").remove();
    // $(this).parent().remove();
});

});
```

```css
.swimlanes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swimlanes__column {
  min-width: 15rem;
  flex: 1;
  background: #f2f2f3;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.swimlanes__list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swimlanes__listItem {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .swimlanes {
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="colBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add News Column</button>
</div>

<section id="laneSection" class="swimlanes">
  <div id="swimlane" class="swimlanes__column">
    <h6>
      <!-- Heading structure [BoardName]: [ListName]. Where boardName links to the Board -->
      <div>Website<i class="bi bi-pen"></i> <button id="del" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button>
      </div>
      <button id="rowBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add New Item</button>
    </h6>
    <ul id="lane" class="swimlanes__list">
      <li id="laneItem" class="swimlanes__listItem">Dummy content goes here</li>
      <li id="laneItem" class="swimlanes__listItem">Dummy content goes here</li>
      <li id="laneItem" class="swimlanes__listItem">Dummy content goes here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would like to delete the clicked row and now only the first row.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. You are violating that before you start cloning elements already.

Comment: Because you are removing element based on id and id attribute is unique within the entire page. You need to change it to use classes and close the class `.swimlane` of only clicked element using `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all ids and use `class` instead . Then , whenever your button is clicked you can use `$(".swimlanes__column:first").clone()` to clone first div inside your section  . Also , as these elements are dynamically created you need to bind your dynamically created elements with static elements i.e : `$(".swimlanes").on("click", ".del", function(e) {` and inside this use `$(this).closest(".swimlanes__column").remove()` to remove entire div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#colBtn').click(function() {
    //clone first one 
    $("#laneSection").append($(".swimlanes__column:first").clone());
  });
  $('#rowBtn').click(function() {
    $("#lane").append($(".swimlanes__list:first").clone());
  });
  //use it like this because dynamically created
  $(".swimlanes").on("click", ".del", function(e) {
    //delete closest one 
    $(this).closest(".swimlanes__column").remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.swimlanes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swimlanes__column {
  min-width: 15rem;
  flex: 1;
  background: #f2f2f3;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.swimlanes__list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swimlanes__listItem {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .swimlanes {
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="colBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add News Column</button>
</div>

<section id="laneSection" class="swimlanes">
  <!--removed all ids-->
  <div class="swimlanes__column">
    <h6>
      <!-- Heading structure [BoardName]: [ListName]. Where boardName links to the Board -->
      <div>Website<i class="bi bi-pen"></i> <button type="button" class="btn del btn-danger btn-sm">X</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn rowBtn btn-primary btn-sm">Add New Item</button>
    </h6>
    <ul class="swimlanes__list">
      <li class="swimlanes__listItem">Dummy content goes here</li>
      <li class="swimlanes__listItem">Dummy content goes here</li>
      <li class="swimlanes__listItem">Dummy content goes here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```